# How can I constrain drawing on the <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch

I want to create a mobile web page where a shape appears on the screen, the user can only traces over the outline of the shape with his/her finger and then a new shape will appear. This [library](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) has a few good examples of what I am looking to do, just with more shapes. I have already found a couple of good examples for drawing on the canvas on a touch device [here](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/multiuser-draw-html5-canvas-tutorial/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events#Example). The thing I don't know is how to constrain the line so you are only drawing on the path with a single continuous line. Is there something built in that will let me specify the only path you can draw, or do I have to write that logic by hand?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by 'constraint'.

Comment: I updated the question a bit, but the shape is there, and you will only be able to trace the outline of that shape.

Answer (score 2):

We can split the issue into two parts :
1) knowing if the user is on the path.
2) knowing if the user went on all path parts.

For 1), we can use the isPointInPath context2D method to know if the mouse/touch point (x,y) is on the curve. The constraint here is that you must build a closed surface, meaning a surface drawn by a fill(), not one built with a stroke().  So in case you are stroking thick lines, you have to do some little math to build the corresponding figures out of moveTo+lineTo+fill.

For 2) : build a list of 'check-points' for your shape. You might have, for instance 8 control points for a circle. Then decide of a distance at which the user will 'activate' the check point.  Now the algorithm is, in pseudo-code:

```
 mouseDown => check()
 mouseMove => if mouse is down, check()

 checkPointList = [  [ 10, 40, false ] , [ centerX, centerY, isChecked], ... ] ;
 checked = 0;

 function check() {
    clear screen
    draw the path
    if (mouse down and mouse point on path) {
       for ( checkPoint in CheckPointList) {
           if (checkPoint near enough of mouse) {
              checkPoint[3]=true;
              checked++;
           }
       }
    if (checked == checkPointList.length) ==>>> User DID draw all the shape.
    }  else
    clear the flags of the checkPointList;      
    checked=0;
 }
```

I did a moooost simple demo here, which quites work.
The control points are shown in red when disactivated, green when activated :

http://jsbin.com/wekaxiguwiyo/1/edit?js,output

```
// boilerplate
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  drawShape();  
  drawCP();
}

// Shape
function drawShape() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(30,5);
  ctx.lineTo(80,5);
  ctx.lineTo(80, 300);
  ctx.lineTo(30,300);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth= 16;
  ctx.fillStyle='#000';
  ctx.fill();
}

// Control points
var points = [ [50, 50, false], [50,120, false], [50, 190, false],[50,260, false ]  ];
var pointsCount = 0;

function drawCP() {
  for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    ctx.fillStyle=p[2]?'#0F0':'#F00';
    ctx.fillRect(p[0]-1, p[1]-1, 2, 2);
  }
}

function resetCP() {
  for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    points[i][2]=false;
  }
  pointsCount=0;
}

function testCP(x,y) {
  var d=30;
  d=sq(d);
  for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    if (sq(points[i][0]-x)+sq(points[i][1]-y)<d) { 
      if (!points[i][2]) pointsCount++;
      points[i][2]=true
    };
  }
}

function sq(x) { return x*x; }

//
draw();

// most simple event handling
addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

var r = cv.getBoundingClientRect();

function mouseMove(e) {
  var x = e.pageX-r.left;
  var y = e.pageY-r.top;
  draw();
  ctx.fillStyle='#000';

  if (ctx.isPointInPath(x,y)) { 
      ctx.fillStyle='#F00';
      testCP(x,y);
  } else {
      resetCP();
  }
  ctx.fillRect(x-3,y-3,6,6);
  var pathDrawn = (pointsCount == points.length);
  if (pathDrawn) ctx.fillText('Shape drawn!!', 150, 150);
}
```